# spring boot security dao authentication - authorities removed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Developing a spring boot application that implements spring boot security basic authentication database based security.  Have implemented UserDetailsService and overrode the loadUserByUsername method. Stepping through the method I find that the username, password and role information is successfully retrieved from my database user table.

My UserDetailsService loadUserByUsername code is

```
  @Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserInfo activeUserInfo = userInfoDAO.getActiveUser(userName);
    SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(activeUserInfo.getRole());
    User(activeUserInfo.getUserName(),
            activeUserInfo.getPassword(), Arrays.asList(authority));
    return userDetails;
}
```

Stepping back into DaoAUthenticationProvider retrieveUser contains the values returned from the user table lookup but the AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider authentication method shows the authorities to be a zero length array, username and password are correctly returned.  Not having the authorities value is causing a 401 bad credentials error to be returned.

I am testing with postman.  Working with MySql 5.7.11 with a user table defined using this:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
);
```

The password is stored using the BCryptPasswordEncoder and am sending the password in plain text via postman.

My application.properties are defined as:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/actotracker?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Dial0gicRots
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
security.basic.enabled=true
security.basic.realm=Spring
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Have tried manually setting the authorities values to "ROLE_ADMIN" without impacting the results.  Pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Java version 1.8
Spring boot 1.5.3.RELEASE

Code where I register the password encoder:

```
  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);
@Autowired
private AppUserDetailService appUserDetailsService;
@Autowired
private AppAuthenticationEntryPoint appAuthenticationEntryPoint;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    log.info("In configure");
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN","ROLE_USER")
            .and().httpBasic().realmName("Spring")
         //   .and().httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(appAuthenticationEntryPoint);
}
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    log.info("configGlobal");
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

Postman values:
http://localhost:8080/user/distances
username field: tim
password: plain text password value
authentication set to basic authentication

Comment: debugged the code a bit further.  additionalAuthenticationChecks in AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider's isPasswordValid check is failing.  Did an evaluate of the presentedpassword and the userDetails.getPassword() and the values match.  The salt value is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dur was correct, the 401 was caused by a password mismatch.  I had written a small routine to take a plain text string and bcrypt it.
`

```
        String creds = "xxxxxxx";       
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String encPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(creds);
```

I used /stored the encPassword value in my user authentication table.

Stepping into BCryptPasswordEncoder class, BCrypt.checkpw, I found that my raw text string was converted to a differant encrypted value.  Updated my database user table entry with the new encrypted value and my authorization was successful.